# How to retrieve the Agent for a specific Release

Tags: tfs, azure-devops, tfs-sdk, azure-devops-rest-api

The TFS Rest API allows me to get a specific Release for a Team Project

Ex. `https://bla.visualstudio.com/MySuperProject/_apis/release/releases/666`

I already found, how to get the related Pool of the Release. But is it possible to retrieve the Agent where the Release was deployed using the TFS Rest API ?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can get the release with all the details by calling REST API as shown below. You should use youraccount.**vsrm.visualstudio**

```
https://yourVSTSAccount.vsrm.visualstudio.com/yourproject/_apis/release/releases/releaseid
```

example

```
https://myac.vsrm.visualstudio.com/Project%20X/_apis/release/releases/106
```

gives the release agent in deployment steps as shown below

[image]